# Custom app-specific permissions for RBAC on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, rbac

Amazon Cognito provides capabilities for Role Based Access Control (RBAC) that allows an admin to either permit or deny user access to various AWS resources. However, suppose I have a serverless webapp that runs on AWS Lambda and uses Cognito for user management. My app has its own set of app-specific actions (eg add a widget, delete a wombat, update a foo). My database objects have relationships with each other (eg every wombat owns multiple foo's). I want to have record level permissions (eg this user can only delete this foo if the user owns the wombat to which this foo belongs). These are app-specific permissions. It would be a giant pain to map each of these app-specific permissions (which I can easily understand in my head as the developer of the webapp) to the underlying AWS services. Furthermore, if I ever want to switch to a different AWS service or switch to some other cloud service provider, I would have to completely redo all my permissions. It would be much better to have a way to have the app admin/designer (eg me) create my app-specific set of semantically meaningful permissions and have a service that I can query to see if the given user has a given permission for the requested action on this object. Does AWS provide such a service, or would I have to maintain my own app-specific permission/role database tables and roll my own functionality to provide this?

Any suggestions? I'm using python for the backend language and MYSQL on Amazon RDS for the DB.